# Count number of Insertions in BST

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have a BST class of Strings with a global variable called `numInsertions` that counts the number of insertions I do into the BST. I am not sure this gives the correct results as I do not know recursion very well, please help me verify

```
public void insert(String key)
  {
    if(isEmpty())
    {
      root = new Node(key);
      numInsertions++;
    }
    else
      numInsertions = 1+insert(key, root);
  }
  public int insert(String key, Node curr)
  {
    int result = 1;
    if(key.compareTo(curr.getKey())<0)
    {
      if(curr.getLeftChild()==null)
      {
        Node newNode = new Node(key);
        curr.setLeftChild(newNode);
      }
      else
        result = result +insert(key,curr.getLeftChild());
    }
    else
    {
      if(curr.getRightChild()==null)
      {
        Node newNode = new Node(key);
        curr.setRightChild(newNode);
      }
      else
        result = result +insert(key,curr.getRightChild());
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a test case for you class and test that the class is behaving properly. Let's say your class is named BST and you can access the instance variable 'numberOfInserts' with a method named 'size()', a simple test case for testing insertions (without any 3rd party libraries) could be placed in the main method of your test class. Something like:

```
BST bst = new BST();
//test insertion of 100 items
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ){
    bst.insert(String.valueOf(i));
    if ( bst.size() != i+1 ){
        throw new Exception("Invalid BST size " + bst.size());
    }
}
```

In this example, an Exception will be thrown if the class does not behave properly. If it misbehaves, you then can step into a debugger (or use System.out.println) to try and debug the application.